# KendoUI grid for angularjs don't show data after data-binding

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, kendo-ui-grid

I attempt bind data to Kendo UI grid for AngularJS.
Folowing is asp.net mvc controller method:

```
public string GetCdcReport()
{
    return
        "[{\"ProductID\":1,\"ProductName\":\"Chai\",\"UnitPrice\":18,\"UnitsInStock\":39,\"Discontinued\":false}," +
        "{\"ProductID\":2,\"ProductName\":\"Chang\",\"UnitPrice\":19,\"UnitsInStock\":17,\"Discontinued\":false}]";
}
```

AngularJs service method:

```
function getImportResultReport() {
    return httpPost('getCdcReport');
}
```

Data-binding in angularjs controller:

```
vm.mainGridOptions = {
    columns: [
        { field: "ProductID", title: "ID" },
        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { command: [{ template: "<button class='k-button' ng-click='showDetails(dataItem)'>Show details</button>" }] },
    ],
    pageable: true,
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 5,
        transport: {
            read: function (e) {
                dataservice.getImportResultReport().
                then(function (data) {
                        e.success(data);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This code don't return error. Grid rendering 37 pages of 5 rows, but they is empty.
I think that grid must know what type of data set for binding. In my case it is jSon. How set json type for grid datasource? Or what is wrong if don't need to do this?

Comment: mmm i think you don't bind the properties of your json to html .. i think KEndo ui have a way to decalre which columns wioth wich property of your json

Comment: That's the json string, did you parse it in the success response?

Comment: Thanks. This works if i write `e.success(JSON.parse(data))`.